# .Net Core with WS-Federation generates large wctx

Tags: .net-core, ws-federation

I am attempting to learn how to use WS-Federation in a .NET Core application. I am attempting a basic step of having my client application redirect to an authentication service (defined in my FederationMetadata.xml file), but when I attempt to access a controller requiring authentication [url in this case is http://localhost/STSAwareApp/Test], my redirect url becomes too large to be usable (I get a 404.15, query string is too large).

Since I'm new to WS-Federation, I'm assuming that I have a configuration issue in my startup:

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddWsFederation(authenticationScheme: "WsFederation", displayName: "Test WS-Fed", options =>
        {
             options.Wtrealm = "http://localhost/STSAwareApp/Test";
             options.MetadataAddress = "http://localhost/STSAwareApp/files/FederationMetadata.xml";
             options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        }).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "TestStsAuth";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });

        services.AddLogging(
             builder =>
             {
                 builder.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Trace)
                           .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Trace)
                           .AddConsole();
                    });
            }
    }
```

Here is an example of the redirect URL that is getting generated (just for completeness sake):
http://localhost:80/STSAwareApp/Test?wtrealm=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FSTSAwareApp%2FTest&wa=wsignin1.0&wreply=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FSTSAwareApp%2Fsignin-wsfed&wctx=CfDJ8O7dpxEY6MBCgxct4kkpp1gFIwYvsJN7p6zOuAiyltKmCqff605h1uCh7ZBNM6WneU_7XlxHKAt7CYmBdXG_e19L8z-p64d21gJjDJCdjOkfNieQWNRSPQPGZDUL8eBEVqs4vWaKN-sof8lnblDbySiP8NJPR945c8IYqRwaf7ZBZ-_IxoWZLN_OgMOgFnU5XjtDeUfFCcHh0dtGwSc4PVDPxhKIpxb3JyIEMBRA19qZpudqQEylX6WHek5LkNK1IDbWDv2ll9F5HCJSQxvpVDrLw62dBfF6IDNg3Ar8q2Yr_bpV1gA1RR7kHp3Gs4soxfZENfvi96qkPJs4ZOqvUYjRQjho34Lkc9VH5q2w7n4Oty6abFXs_jeDQQN7ZyFBGQrb-wxBZBEuvNJAFp-ckhGVCeKrtdmXS4bVAvbEtPAEtLHXJpv82Y843_UVCeAQycMjmz2stIovI-HiKAWwCkoc03J7gOlTEwyrn1cR-Ia3QWN4mPN2ncqxW5e80kamNDIDmRxiWoox1Z6x5SATSIO3KergXc7VE1G8-2gLicc8_flyLR6NXUAdDRZTnxGzChHzf2L1eqjm0K_PvioAdqJNuFDlFMeGyfarEbXahAqpchuDvSgolSEKgGO-uLw5GEdCS-5cX_Ztt3bAjbXzkPMdhzYbXFWTDdYTMMMta18nhzgAk5CIzDvo1BmniWGdwUy-lAWm9BoNd4TsroQa-F8NJ86K4sixQIqRqQ-D-Bf_672hHbIkY1QEEe8tqTH-1Qwn9K5RY5sVFQLu0Ec4bp0Zj2EDis-GAtMxhp6761MciYjjhqgORhe3gsLeej5GEY0AErXUOCxdghQKs-waLQtNQ2F4Xn226DYp6NVn8bLs5pu4mFblaWRn9cVzKPHUosRT9BjKqbnLpCCC0A4cOXec-G5znWLOXa6G4qsZjFl5h79MwStDnzP6GU2Wg6TaLG83783f6bRsJwX8blc1CMEjByphkpZp-VdR6FytLXvu4bh8gQQo2K3ad76pNlF8HnA4y1f0p86A82i2IPPDrOeW6YFupzZRITSFz-JvhjAZbkSzu26bgqgHNVTIz1ebu9mHIMQzGzpAu0rFIl16HszR7Omxn8TljADTCCLasQyLNRUIXSA5teeowULetXEv_rmOr6ANkk0kQ-q3pPuiOzkA0aFV6g1jYQ-JvS9K817IafEes7akoDrPbeHEmvD5sWzxERlMtnEQtYwcrPiOroWXIh1QgLjqUgTxtagWmkzoBWVM5PnNmMVkk0alyTgZKOomTcZN8ePkLRp4sY0d0D_uqb0Rn_s757Nb-oDztAz6SLOkCzWnPDif3eIAFTZy24v_oYr3SOFfvM2J-_t0kg3zlRovg25_bPPSs-qyfrMMBSbMammB5e7SKbIna4dPhMdv93Vm6I2GwJ8-VY-pAuBT4MQXPLD1VwdiBT3hWsZOoeMUl1JuL7B9pJDAMBNO2OUTaRb7dajP3VsA09XSgVrBeZ1Hvk733TrzFVoR5KQgHS4qw9cxquRmqP2XfEYTQocB-mUL4b-n0h3RN2qzaHn_VH2pZDV842YcanF4SZ8dDPB4EnLCWU7pf67IwvruInvu8MXg01xNoURh6rKLmSwikbgsEM7Es87RMQSEvar1QixBId9XMO1YiHVvGAdJoivUveJSO1T8Aj4A2xFllBjtD4SfnJc5UDTQ7UxGnVmIVw6pwS9N26U_u09n-T4j5R-ZVQyCNgSjoNRg-3jmMatXcAhT4vJgO-kRuzMiBKnavJ7EPyS8Th8KUK0ws1tQYQKmQQGvd7DT_GRC0wXT8HrTZ1uxTmxxDibzyCLxJZmulLHPcYaXwpWw6j56vOxgCrGy-3L5GtfnXNN1UdE3QzbE6_XL3xF8B3uD6Z5g5ZB_ZR4Q0QS0K9Kb6guaAtxEJYKc2eE2DZ2OpMNtyw5imNYt9crd5J4mB05GR7c0Nur2vqzk1mGM56_0IQD9L4HV4fXNmQuprEpwNZ41NyW-bhcVS30rZn73WLc-XBlNWhCrE_HiTWzCDOn9juofX7_C2AcQypJt-aweXEN5uxRWPp_W9qFJNblrkjzAEr3o7_dylYLYTstOvW4dYuIE4WlTUiJdJF3Iy02whGQUpclOINsxZ3wotkKY2JsnUzsolSeIfWe-es8soGOkPnDSthgjRbpTxltmVz10L0kAo4zckz4HvhEmziWPsGWZH1UVtRKLniT60qq9PPxeuu_dsodov-ByanyRwMHlkzCJhmSBDE0

I'm under the assumption that the url is not only incorrect because the wctx is too long, but it should be attempting to redirect to a different service [http://localhost/STS/V1], it is attempting to the original url with the federation parameters in the query string. I think that the wctx should be smaller, because even if I increase the size of my URL limits, it just continues to grow.

Comment: I believe that the reason that the wctx is large is because of the url redirecting to itself. So the issue is why isn't the redirect going to the expected URL.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with this was that the FederationMetadata.xml document was not configured correctly. Not exactly sure what was wrong, but instead of attempting to have a valid xml document, it was simpler to update the Configuration property of the WsFederationOptions. Attached is the updated Startup call:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddWsFederation(authenticationScheme: "WsFederation", displayName: "Test WS-Fed", options =>
    {
        WsFederationConfiguration configuration = new WsFederationConfiguration();
        configuration.TokenEndpoint = "http://localhost/STSSpike/V1";
        options.Configuration = configuration;
        options.Wtrealm = "http://localhost/STSAwareApp/Test";
    }).AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "TestStsAuth";
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    });

    services.AddLogging(
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Trace)
                   .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Trace)
                   .AddConsole();
        });
}
```

Guessing that this is a pretty localized issue, so might want to close.